# In Apostol's book, Calculus. How is the height of the outer rectangle calculated in Figure 1.5?

Tags: calculus

At the beginning of the book, in Figure 1.5, Apostol sets that the altitude of the outer rectangle is $ (\frac{kb}{n})^2 $. How does he get this height?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Presumably on this parabolic segment $y=x^2$ so the height is $x^2=\left(\dfrac{kb}n\right)^2$

Comment: Isn't that the graph of the function $\;f(x)=x^2\;$ ? This is quite an important information not to give it explicitly...

Comment: Just realized it is mentioned. He mentions it some paragraphs above. I completely missed the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the parabola is $y = f(x) = x^2$.  So when the $x$-coordinate is $x = kb/n$, the $y$-coordinate is the square, and the height of the rectangle is simply this value.

To show that the $x$-coordinate of the lower-right corner of the $k^{\rm th}$ rectangle is $kb/n$, it is simple to see that if there are $n$ rectangles of equal width partitioning the interval from $0$ to $b$, then each rectangle has width $b/n$.  The first rectangle then has its base on $[0, b/n]$, the second on $[b/n, 2b/n]$, etc.